# How can I prevent SMB digital signing from killing SSIS performance?

Tags: ssis, windows-server

My company recently turned on SMB digital signing on the Windows 2012 r2 server that runs SSIS. This has had a severe impact on data transfer performance. The security team did this and I can't get them to turn it off. Are there any workarounds? How can I prevent SMB digital signing from killing SSIS performance?